# DataGridView Add Multiple Rows for List in List Object

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two classes `Employee` and `Department` as follows

```
class Employee
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Departments> AssociatedDepartment {get;set;}
}

class Department
{
   public string DepartmentID {get;set;}
   public string DepartmentName {get;set;}
}
```

I am binding a `DataGridView` with `List<Employee>`. It is showing list of `Employees` but not `Department` of the employees.

```
List<Employee> employeeList = GetEmployeeList();

if (employeeList != null)
{
     grdResponse.DataSource = employeeList;
}
```

Now it is showing following data.

```
ID  Name  
---------
1   Joe  
2   Tim
```

What should I do to get following?

```
ID  Name Department 
--------------------
1   Joe  Software
1   Joe  Management
2   Tim  Hardware
```

Comment: According to your design `An Employee can have more than one department public List<Departments> AssociatedDepartment {get;set;}`

Comment: Yes an `Employee` can have more than one `Department`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extend `Employee` class with get-only property (the column will be ReadOnly)

```
class Employee
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Departments
    {
        get 
        { 
           if (AssociatedDepartment == null || AssociatedDepartment.Count == 0)
              return string.Empty;
           return string.Join(", ", AssociatedDepartment.Select(d => d.DepartmentName));
        }
    }

    public List<Department> AssociatedDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following property in Employee :

```
public string Department
{
    get
    {
        string departments = string.Empty;
        foreach (Department department in AssociatedDepartment)
        {
            if (departments.Length != 0)
                departments += ", ";
            departments += department.DepartmentName;
        }
        return departments;
    }
}
```